# c# How to use Visio.Shape properties related to fields

Tags: c#, shapes, visio, user-defined

Im having a few problems with interacting with Visio.Shape items using C#.

I am able to loop through each shape within a page, when i do myShapeObj.Text i tend to get the correct text back. However, my visio document has the shape linked to a custom field. 
Fields > Custom Formuls = ThisDoc!User.mycustomproperty.

I have a User-Defined Cell called "User.mycustomproperty" which holds a value such as "02a", "03" etc
The string returns comes up as not recognised character when shown in visual Studio's debug window.
Is it possible to parse the value as text?

Also a second related question:
Is there an easy way to get/set this User-defined Cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main properties for accessing a shape's text - one is `Shape.Text`, as you know, and the other is `Shape.Characters`.  The latter returns a `Characters` object which has a number of members for reading and manipulating the text.

Amongst these is a `Characters.Text` property that returns the entire text including expanded fields.

So, if you have three shapes like this:

[image]

...and then run this code:

```
void Main()
{
    var vApp = MyExtensions.GetRunningVisio();
    var vPag = vApp.ActivePage;
    foreach (Visio.Shape shp in vPag.Shapes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Text: {shp.Text} \nCharacters: {shp.Characters.Text}\n");
    }
}
```

...you'll get the following output:

Text: Shape 1 with no field

Characters: Shape 1 with no field

Text: Shape 2 with a doc field [￼]

Characters: Shape 2 with a doc field [02a]

Text: Shape 3 with datetime field [￼]

Characters: Shape 3 with datetime field [Monday, 20 November 2017]

Here you can see that `Shape.Text` returns the collapsed field and `Shape.Characters.Text` returns the expanded version.

Note that `GetRunningVisio` is my extension method for using with LinqPad:

http://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2015/12/getting-started-with-c-in-linqpad-with-visio.html

...but it's up to you how you get hold of the application object.

---

For your second question about setting User cells then I would do something like this:

```
const string targetCellName = "User.mycustomproperty";
var docSheet = vDoc.DocumentSheet;
if (docSheet.CellExistsU[targetCellName, (short)0] != 0)
{
    vDoc.DocumentSheet.CellsU[targetCellName].FormulaU = @"=""04a""";
}
```

Comment: Excellent, with a slight bit of tinkering and your advice, I've managed to sort everything. This has saved me soooo much time doing really tedious manual tasks